# How to execute Ruby scripts on Windows 7 with minimal technical effort?

Tags: windows-7, ruby

I've written some Ruby scrappers which will be used by some non-technical guys. I want to make these Ruby scripts executable on Windows with minimal effort. What are my options beside installing Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 3 approaches to your problem.

**1. Install ruby**.

Pros: minimal programming effort needed, ability to make changes to script

Cons: you will need to install ruby on every pc where script needs to be run

**2. Rewrite your script into powershell.**

Pros: usage of built-in tool, ability to make changes to script

Cons: a lot of programming effort needed

**3. User compiler like http://ocra.rubyforge.org/ to make .exe from your script**

Pros: easiest solution

Cons: you will need to recompile exe each time you make changes to your script, may be problems with different ruby versions